# Select the 2sd specified letter of each line in Visual Code Studio

Tags: visual-studio-code, selection

Sorry if the title isn't really explicit, i don't really know how to formulate it.

What i'm trying to achieve, is to select for exemple, the second or third "|" character of each lines.

Ex:

```
Land_Misc_Well_Pump_Yellow|5761.283691|**CURSOR HERE**118.056274|4587.1308593.000000|0.000000|0.000000
bldr_Decal_dirt_damage_long3|5760.770996|**CURSOR HERE**117.330002|4600.03222725.000019|0.000000|0.000000
bldr_sign_nodumping|5768.204102|**CURSOR HERE**118.897118|4635.286621-135.944122|3.754690|2.833742
```

I don't know if this is possible, but i'm trying to recover a file full of these lines that got "corrupted", and this would make it so much easier to fix it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following regex to select from the begin of the line up to the second `|`

```
^([^|]*\|){2}
```

1. Click in the text
2. Use menu **Select** > **Select All Occurrences** (Ctrl+Shift+L)
3. Use **Arrow Right**